# Move viewpoint of ScrollPane on Button click

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

There is concept of my JavaFX applictions:

[image: Concept]

All screens in one `ScrollPane`.

For example, if user click on button "Options" in `loginScreen` i want to animate Y-value of `ViewPort` to move it to `optionsScreen`.

How can i programmatically move `viewport` of ScrollPane with smooth animation?

Or you can offer better idea?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://w3facility.org/question/javafx-scrollpane-programmatically-moving-the-viewport-centering-content/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I programmatically move viewport of ScrollPane with smooth animation?

You can use a combination of [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) and [vvalueProperty of ScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vvalueProperty--) to perform a smooth animation of scrolling.

Here is a simple application where you I have three sections

- Top
- Center
- Bottom

I am changing the `vvalue` of the ScrollPane through a `Timeline` on the action of the button.

The vvalue can have a value between **0.0 to 1.0**, so you may have to do your own calculations to find the exact value which you want to be assigned to it.

The [KeyValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html) performs the operation on `scrollRoot.vvalueProperty()`.

The [KeyFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html) for the complete timeline is set at `500 milliseconds`. You may *increase* or *decrease* it depending on the time you want the animation to run.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    // For just adjusting the center rectangle w.r.t ScrollPane
    private final int ADJUSTMENT_RATIO = 175;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle topRegion = new Rectangle(300, 300, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        StackPane top = new StackPane(topRegion, new Label("Top"));

        Rectangle centerRegion = new Rectangle(300, 300, Color.GOLDENROD);
        StackPane center = new StackPane(centerRegion, new Label("center"));

        Rectangle bottomRegion = new Rectangle(300, 300, Color.BISQUE);
        StackPane bottom = new StackPane(bottomRegion, new Label("bottom"));

        Button topButton = new Button("Top");
        Button centerButton = new Button("Center");
        Button bottomButton = new Button("Bottom");

        HBox buttonBox = new HBox(15, topButton, centerButton, bottomButton);
        buttonBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        buttonBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        final VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(top, center, bottom);

        ScrollPane scrollRoot = new ScrollPane(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(buttonBox, scrollRoot));
        stage.setTitle("Market");
        stage.setWidth(350);
        stage.setHeight(400);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        topButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(scrollRoot.vvalueProperty(), 0.0);
            final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            timeline.play();
        });

        centerButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(scrollRoot.vvalueProperty(), (top.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() + ADJUSTMENT_RATIO) / root.getHeight());
            final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            timeline.play();
        });

        bottomButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(scrollRoot.vvalueProperty(), 1.0);
            final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            timeline.play();
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you! `vvalueProperty` exactly what I was looking for!